# Which two letters to use to show the most typographic concepts?

Tags: fonts, typography, typesetting, type-theory

I’m putting letters on a typographic grid complemented by a chart to show and name typographic concepts.
The list of terms shouldn’t be exhaustive, but should contain the most important ones, e.g.:

- the different lines (baseline, midline etc.)
- open and closed counters
- ascenders and descenders
- different heights and widths

I don’t have enough space for a full-fledged »Hamburgefonstiv«: two letters is all I get.

Which combination (majuscules or minuscules) can I use that embodies the most typographic concepts?

An example for Chinese text (without numbering) I already finished (inspired by Zippel 2011, ISBN 978-3-87439-818-3):

[image]

Comment: What about simple icons? An image sample of a part of your design will be useful to help you.

Comment: Which typeface?

Comment: Does it matter which two "letters"? i.e. are you limited to a specific script/alphabet etc?

Comment: @Danielillo I added an example of what I have in mind.

Comment: @Lucian I’ll be using Linux Libertine, in particular the display font (http://libertine-fonts.org/).

Comment: Uhm, ok :)) Not sure how asian characters work, my answer below applies to latin characters.

Comment: @Lucian I’ll show letters of the Latin alphabet. I just added the example because I’m comparing typographic concepts, and I already had this ready.

Comment: What do the gaps between the opposite-facing arrows in the Chinese example indicate? Or rather, why is the gap centred in the horizontal lines, but off-centre in the vertical ones?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet (I hope this "poke" works, the auto-complete doesn't trigger on my mobile device; could you tell me if you got notified of this comment?) The gaps are just blanks for the numbers that are defined in a separate TeX file. Doing it that way has the advantage that all numbers and letters are automatically  set in the same settings as the rest of the document (font, size, style).

Comment: Oh, I see! Yes, the notification did work. :-)

Comment: You may want to consider combinations such as AV which illustrate kerning, though they're quite poor when it comes to descenders, ascenders, etc. Not sure if there are any combinations that would show both.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Probably, it doesn’t matter much to your audience whether you use letters they are familiar with, as long as they are clearly recognisable as letters. Hence I suggest *Ȩ̂* (E with circumflex and cedilla) and *þ̇* (thorn with dot accent):

[image: Anatomy]

You get:

- letter anatomy:

  1. aperture
  2. apex
  3. arm
  4. ascender
  5. bar
  6. beak
  7. bowl or lobe
  8. closed and open counters
  9. descender
  10. neck
  11. overshoot
  12. bilateral and unilateral, bracketed serifs
  13. shoulder
  14. stem
  15. terminal
  16. tie
  17. tittle
  18. vertex/crotch
- lines and heights:

  - *x* height
  - cap height
  - baseline
  - ascender and descender lines
  - accent heights
- several stroke widths
- glyph categories:

  - uppercase
  - lowercase
  - accent
  - diacritcal mark

As far as I can see, the [anatomical components](https://typedecon.com/blogs/type-glossary) that are missing and not specific to a single letter (there are several terms which only exist to describe the letter *g*), are leg, spur, teardrop, and tail.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. The accents are a very good suggestion. While strictly speaking it doesn't matter which letters I use, I may opt for an alternative to that thorn, even if it means that I lose some information.

Comment: Hmm, then it really depends on your priorities. Are an italic *f* or even better *ß* an option?

Comment: Ja, sind sie ;)

Comment: @Philipp: In that case, my best quick guess are an *Ą̈* (*A* with diaeresis and ogonek) and an italic *ß.*

Answer (score 8):

Kind of depends on the typeface being used, but I would show a lowercase `b` and a `p` and if possible, an `m`. This will show the extremes in most typefaces, the tallest, the lowest, the widest.

Another thing you can do without using extra space is to add the uppercase variants in the background with a very thin gray outline or fill.

[image]

Comment: A combination like yours is what I had in mind, thanks for your answer! I will only use two letters, but the outlines are a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

If I have to make it:

- Group concepts, as you did in the question
- Choose the inicial letter of the group and an order number
- For single items, two initials or two first letters
- In the chart, try to separate *groups* and *single items*

[image: graphic]

Something like that¿?:

[graphicdesign.stackexchange.answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109578/120647)

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. At least, I don’t really see how this answers the question asked.

Comment: You are right!!!

Answer (score 1):

The characters `Qh` would, in at least some fonts, cover most of those points.  The `Q` has a closed counter and the `h` has an open one.  The `Q` has (in some fonts) a descender while `h` has an ascender.  Neither character would typically reach to the maximum descender depth, but `h` would typically have a maximum or near-maximum-height ascender along with a counter whose size is controlled by the lowercase x height; the top of the Q would line up with the uppercase height.